# So I broke networking and lots of stuff upgrading to 16.04.2 over SSH. How to reinstall a samba server easily?

Tags: networking, upgrade, ssh, samba

I use this box as a homemade NAS for my personal stuff.

Tonite I ran the dist--release-upgrade over SSH and my laptop went to sleep sadly ending the session during the upgrade I was remotely doing.

I know I did it  against the nasbox best wishes and warnings. A man has to be confortably on the couch you know.

Long story short, Eth0 ain't coming up anymore, and if I run the command again (to run the upgrade again), it says is missing something in a python script

I tried going back to older kernels at boot to no avail.

I'm figuring at this point I should just reinstall from scratch

I was running

-Samba
   -Some FTP deaomon (for my wireless scanner dump space, it aint doing SMB)
   -madm for software raid mirroring
   -a rclone chron job to put that in the big sky for cheap.

What should I do to have the less samba reconfig possible? Just save what is in /etc/samba and reinstall?

I will obviously make a copy of my files on removable media before doing anything too cowboy.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yup the configuration files are in `/etc/samba/` that's pretty much all you need once you installed samba just copy those files back in there restart the service and everything should be set-up. Don't forget to create the right directories, users and user rights etc...

Comment: Is there a way to import users easily?